# How to simulate a React component that uses the document object?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am currently writing unit tests for a react component in my application. The react component utilize the DOM api such as document.getElementById().
When I use shallow() or mount() from enzyme, I get an error saying that the document object is null:
[image]

I thought that jest already comes with jsdom as a headless browser. How can I fixed this issue to access a fake dom object?

Comment: you can use [ document && document... ], and then, test at updateProdSpan. Well, it only will run the test, maybe you need to mock the document object with jest.mock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the component preferably shouldn't use DOM directly because this affects testability and SSR. Rven if it uses, it preferably should use relative queries, not `document`.

JSDOM is not headless browser but Node.js environment that emulates browser environment.

Jest uses [JSDOM by default](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string). `document` cannot be `null`, unless it was specifically assigned to it somewhere. If Jest were configured to not use JSDOM, it would throw `document is not defined` error.

The error states that it is `document.getElementById()` result that is `null`, not `document`.

`document.getElementById` is supposed to be mocked as any other function:

```
jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockReturnValueOnce({ value: '...' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Document can be simulated as follows:

```
    const sampleHtml = `<html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>`;
    document.body.innerHTML = sampleHtml;
```